# SQL*Plus command line parameters overwritten in Windows

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, command-line, sqlplus

I am trying to pass parameter to SQL*Plus script from command line, normally it works like that:

```
sqlplus -s login/pass@sid @script.sql some_param
```

and in script.sql I can reference parameters using ampersand, like that:

```
&1
```

Now, I am doing it in Windows, and two first parameters are overwritten by "Files" string and some path to glogin.sql script - rest of the parameters works fine. So for example when I call sqlplus like that:

```
sqlplus -s login/pass@sid @script.sql par1 par2 par3 par4
```

and the script looks like that:

```
prompt &1
prompt &2
prompt &3
prompt &4
```

I get this output:

```
Files
(x86)\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql
par3
par4
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem - I'm on Windows XP, oracle 11gR2, and the 4 parameters are correctly displayed.

Comment: It looks like the problem lies in the sqlplus path on dist - it's installed on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\BIN" and the values for &1 and &2 are path parts divided by space. Still no idea what can I do with this.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce with the native version of SQL*Plus coming with my Oracle 11gR2, and I cannot reproduce:

`dummy.sql` script:

```
prompt &1
prompt &2
prompt &3
prompt &4

select 1 a from dual;

exit
```

Output:

```
E:\CFM\Dev\SQL>sqlplus -s guest/guest@DEV @dummy.sql 1 2 3 4
1
2
3
4

         A
----------
         1


E:\CFM\Dev\SQL>
```

My first tries would be:

- is your sqlplus executable native (or is it a kind of hand-made batch) ?
- what is your OS ?

UPDATE: after your comments, I guess that `glogin.sql` must be called in some way as a command parameter, but without quotes around. My test works but the client is installed in `C:\oracle` (no blanks), which may be why it works for me...

What I would do is re-install your client in a directory without blanks (why not `C:\oracle`) because I think this could solve your issue.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, SQL*Plus is rather a native one (I am executing a sqlplus.exe). I don't know if it may be connected, but the path to SQL*Plus is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\BIN"
so it looks like &1 is "Files" from the path, and &2 is from that path aswell "(x86)\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\BIN". It's just separated by spaces...

Comment: Per the 11g SQL*Plus documentation, the glogin.sql file is ran at the time that you start SQL*Plus. Specifically, this file is here: $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql. Thus, it is trying to run the glogin.sql script and the space in "Program Files" is messing things up. Perhaps modifying your ORACLE_HOME environment variable to include quotations and perhaps the invocation of glogin.sql will work. If this invocation does not work, then I would re-install as Emmanuel has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Oracle on Windows when **`ORACLE_HOME`** environment variable looks something like `C:\Program Files\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0.3\client_1`

While executing *glogin.sql* script, it is trying to run "`C:\Program`" with parameter as "`Files\Oracle\...\glogin.sql`".

Modifying `ORACLE_HOME` to `C:\Progra~1\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0.3\client_1` should fix the issue.

Through windows CMD, this should do the trick

```
SETX ORACLE_HOME C:\Progra~1\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0.3\client_1
```